# Setting overall path to index for php project

Tags: php, project, routes

Let say there's a structure of files i.e.:

```
models/
controllers/
views/
```

I'd like to set a basic path for the application like a constant domain i.e.:
www.domain.com and route all traffic to this path like:

```
www.domain.com/some/path/to/file -> www.domain.com/correct/path/
www.domain.com/some?url=data -> www.domain.com/correct/path/
```

How to set such a structure route properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a .htaccess file placed in your root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) /correct/path
```

Further reading: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

If your site is hosted at a host-provider, make sure mod_rewrite is provided.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your .htacces file

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^some?url=data$ cargarNoticia.php?id=$1